# How to sanitize Relay.createContainer fragment response before it is passed as props

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs, relay

In creating a container using Relay.CreateContainer, I am passing in a Relay.QL fragment that calls for an array of objects.

This array of objects contains some objects by default that I do not want included.

Is it possible to sanitize this response before it is passed as props to the component I am rendering?

I would like to do something like

```
    export default Relay.createContainer(MyComponent, {
        fragments: {
            viewer: () => Relay.QL`
               ...
            `,
        },
        sanitizeProps: props => props.viewer.filter(type => type.name === 'Pony')
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked in the Relay discord channel and was told one of the following was the proper way to handle this.

1. Create a presentational component and handle the sanitization there (which I am already doing with a filter),
2. OR handle the sanitization within the GrahpQL server its self, and do not pass anything unnecessary into the application (what we are going to implement now with a simple filter).

https://discordapp.com/channels/102860784329052160/102861057189490688